# PHP, how to set class variable value from function

Tags: php, class, constructor

I am creating a class with variable, as you can see from the code below, 
I am want to access

`$allen = new guest(...); echo $allen->userName;`

instead I have to use this

`$allen->getUserName();`

but since username won't change after the class is created, is there a way to do this?

```
<?php 
    class guest {

        var $firstName;
        var $lastName; 
        var $email;
        var $userName;

        function guest($firstName, $lastName, $email) {
            $this->firstName = $firstName; 
            $this->lastName = $lastName; 
            $this->userName = getUserName();  // option 1 
            $this->userName = $this->getUserName(); // option 2

            preg_match('/^.*(?=(@))/i', $this->email, $userName);
            $this->userName = $userName[0];  // this is messy but work


        }
        function getUserName() {
            preg_match('/^.*(?=(@))/i', $this->email, $userName);
            return $userName[0];
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Using `var` for properties in a PHP class is a throwback to PHP 4, only maintained for backward compatibility..... but it is recommended that you use `public`/`protected`/`private` visibility instead.... however, as `var` is treated as `public`, `echo $allen->username;` is perfectly valid

Comment: If you don't want $username to be changed after the class is instantiated, set proper visibilities for your properties

Comment: Are you sure this is your real code, and it works? `getUserName()` refers to `$userName`, not `$this->userName`?

Comment: no, opt 1 and opt 2, it doesn't work, it seem there are conflict b/c getUserName function is written after the  __construct. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deny direct access to your class attribute, you can define it as `private`. By doing that, construction like `$allen->userName` will throw an error. This is also known as encapsulation.

First make sure that you initialize your class object properly. In PHP you should define your constructor using __constructor function. Here is example:

```
       class Guest {
    protected $lastName;
    protected $email;
    protected $lastName;
    protected $userName;

    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $email, $userName){
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->userName = $userName;
    }
    public function getUsername(){
        return $this->userName;
    }      
}
```

The constructor receives 4 parameters `$firstName, $lastName, $email, $userName`. In order to create an object of this class you can execute the following code:

```
$allen = new Guest('John', 'Doe', 'some.email@email.com', 'username');
```

To retrieve an username, write the following line:

```
$allen->getUsername();
```

In your current constructor something is bad, becuase I think your `userName` attribute is not properly initialized.

Answer (score 2):

In php5 constructors are not named after the class any more. Instead define it like that:

```
public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $email) 
{
    ///...
}
```

Next, it is unclear how you actually set the property `$this->userName`... you write "this is messy, but it works", however I don't see how this is meant to work, since $userName *should be an array* after calling the `preg_match()`. And saving the array does not make any sense...

Further: if you really define the property `$this->userName` inside the constructor (which makes sense), then why does the getter method `getUserName()` reparse other properties? Instead a plain getter should only return the properties value without much interpretation. That should be fine, since you want to set the value inside the constructor (which probably currently does not work). Maybe this is just a leftover from previous attempts. I just wanted to mention it since it looks odd...

Have fun!

Comment: thanks, yeah i was trying different way to do it, and confuse myself, over it.  I edit the code, to fix the array part, I guess it will be ok to interpreted inside constructor, instead of running a code each time, the value is need.